# Finding a sequence of pixels by color

Tags: java, image, input, pixel, rgb

I have this code:

```
{
Robot robot = new Robot();
Color inputColor = new Color();


Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 770);

    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++) 
        {
            if (image.getRGB(x, y) == inputColor.getRGB()) 
            {
            return 1;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is supposed to, and does, take a screenshot and find in it a pixel specified by the inputColor.  However the program requirements have changed, and now it needs to find a string of pixels 5 long that match a given string.  Is there an easy way to specify this with the existing code, or will I need to change it?  I mean, can I keep the existing code and define inputColor as a string with the values of the 5 pixels, or do I need to change the whole algorithm?

Comment: Do the pixels need to be in a horizontal, left-to-right arrangement, or will any line of 5 matching pixels do?

Comment: horizontal left to right is what im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this would work. Not the best efficiency, but its a bone to chew.

```
int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth())) {
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    if (Array.equals(search, Array.copyOfRange(pixels, i, i + search.length)) {
        //found it
    }
}
```

search would be an array of integers(your colors).

Comment: but how would i put in the 5 pixels i want it to find that's what im having trouble with

Comment: oh, you want 5 pixels, but possibly a different color in each pixel?

Comment: yes in fact each pixel will be a different color, i am looking for an image on screen. the image has five distinct pixels in a row and thats what im looking for

Comment: ok so it works but how do i define in anArray of say 5 how would i define the different pixels, i can define it as a single number but how to define three numbers representing a value?

Comment: `search[0] = (new Color(...)).getRGB();`

Comment: you might want to consider buying a java book for beginners and strengthening your knowledge of the language basics.

Comment: yea thanks chris that works, im getting a few errors most of which i sorted out but i don't know what to do about the cannot find symbol errors pointing at the search in your method

Comment: make sure to `import java.util.Arrays;` and fix my spelling.

Comment: ok im getting an error with this bit of code, the error is:cannot find symbol, variable Array, if(Array.equals(anArray, because Array is not defined and im assuming it is supposed to be the image what should i define Array as?